# Security of cached data in .NET

Tags: c#, caching, datatable, asp.net-4.0

I cached one DataTable fetched from SQL Server 2005 through  C# ASP .NET 4.0 Web App [around 50000 row 32 columns]..

Cache by mean is on **Client-Side**.

I want to know whether the DataTable is secure Or Insecure in the **Cache**?

If insecure than

1. how to get that Data directly from cache and be viewed [not by my Web App as a non developer]
2. how to secure the Data.

Comment: well, what cache are you using? do you mean the HttpContext.Cache?

Comment: no, I used Cache.Insert () and Library : System.Web.Caching;

Comment: HttpContext.Cache **is** System.Web.Caching.Cache... and that is server-side, not client-side

Comment: so it stores the data on Server cache , you mean to say?

Comment: Additional note: you should take extreme care using DataTable with Cache. Since ASP.NET is multi-threaded, and the cache is live objects, you could have multiple threads talking to the same DataTable at once. If you are only *reading*, then fine. But if you are **changing** the table (adding/removing/updating rows, etc), then you ***must*** synchronize (i.e. lock) the data, otherwise you **will** corrupt it.

Comment: yes, the server-side technology that is ASP.NET caches data at the server-side. Where else could it *possibly* access?

Comment: The Process I followed:
1. On Page Load event I stored data in Cache. 
2. Then I close Disable The Network Connection. 
3. and on Button Click I getch the data from Cache. 
and it worked.... even no connection to server.... how it could be possible if its on server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is as secure as the server and the web application are.

If someone has physical access to the box (or through RDP), they can always cause a memory dump and read the values directly from memory.

Depending on how it was written, the application might expose the full Cache.

If either of these are not concerns, you can consider the Cache to be secure.

---

Update:

Seeing as you are talking about client side - **nothing** on the client side can be considered completely safe. The client has physical access to their machine and therefor can do a memory dump and any number of other tricks (including direct memory inspection).

If the client does not need *all* of the data, only share the minimum required. Do not persist it.

Comment: @nirav.patel in what way is the cache on client side? if so, how is this an asp.net question?

Comment: yes ofcourse, I saved the data in DataTable through ASP. NET application. and its working perfectly... I 've done the testing. Just I want to know if user can see that data in any way?

Comment: @nirav.patel - Well, if it is in the ASP.NET application, it resides _in the server_. Can you explain about what you mean about it being cached in the client?

Comment: @nirav then as already answered by Oded and myself: not without compromising your server.

Comment: I think I did some mistake.
See I used System.Web.Caching.Cache in ASP. NET.
1. On Page Load event I stored data in Cache.  2. Then I close Disable The Network Connection.  3. and on Button Click I getch the data from Cache.  and it worked.... even no connection to server.

Comment: @nirav.patel that is what one should expect... the data is held in the server's memory. Note that Cache is shared between ALL USERS on the site too, and is multi-threaded. Be very careful here - I think your conceptual misunderstanding of the ASP.NET Cache could cause data corruption.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the HttpContext.Cache, then that data is in-memory and local to your application. It cannot be arbitrarily queried from outside of your application unless you intentionally provide an API to do so, or your web-server is compromised.

If your web-server is compromised in such a way that a hacker has admin access, they can access process memory, so your data is available. However, at that point the hacker probably has access to your connection string etc, and can have **even more fun** attacking your DB instead (a softer target than looking through process memory).

Comment: cache is in client-side. User's local machine- cache.

Comment: @nirav.patel let me say this very plainly: ***NO IT IS NOT***.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the **DPAPI** (Data Protection API), e.g. using the **[ProtectedMemory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protectedmemory%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**

- Article: [How to: Use Data Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  (framework 3.0)

.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class MemoryProtectionSample
{

    public static void Main()
    {
// Create the original data to be encrypted (The data length should be a multiple of 16).

        byte [] secret = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// Encrypt the data in memory. The result is stored in the same same array as the original data.
        ProtectedMemory.Protect( secret, MemoryProtectionScope.SameLogon );

// Decrypt the data in memory and store in the original array.
        ProtectedMemory.Unprotect( secret, MemoryProtectionScope.SameLogon );
    }

}
```

Comment: encrypting and decrypting constantly is not *necessarily* convenient for cache, especially since it is generally multi-threaded. This also doesn't help the OP with their `DataTable`.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I didn't specify how often the memoery should be (un)protected. Also, do you have a better strategy?

Comment: if you read the comment threads on the question and my/Oded's answer, it is clear that the question isn't relating to securing process memory